# Kubernetes - This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect

Tags: kubernetes

I have installed Kubernetes and Docker. Windows10.
Then ran nginx in docker.
Works great.
Then changed the index.html to have my name in it and made my own image called rk_nginx_base.  Works fine.
Then changed the port for nginx from 80 to 9090.

If I run it in docker (The desktop UI), it works fine...
I see the page in the browser at http://localhost:9090 and get the little icon to launch the browser in the docker UI.
I can refresh the page all I want and it shows the page just fine.

Then I have a kubernetes yaml file ...

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
    app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: rk_nginx_base
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9090
```

Then I do

```
kubectl apply -f .\nginx-deployment.yaml
```

and I see it come up in docker UI.
The first time I hit the server it works. (Probably cache in the browser after running in Docker)
but any subsequent refreshes on any browser (Brave, Chrome, Edge) fails and get the error message

```
This site can’t be reached 
localhost refused to connect.
```

I have tried various solution including adding in a hostPort: 9090 below the containerPort, add a Service for NodePort, and tried kubectl expose -f .\nginx-deployment.yaml

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to check the nginx port configuration?, by default nginx is listening through the port `TPC/80`. So, if you change the port in  kubernetes, you will need change the port in the nginx configuration to listen through the port `TCP/9090`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was the command

```
kubectl expose mynginx
```

was needed to make the internal IP's get forwarded to the localhost IP.